# Scenic sight-seeing locations in and around Gurgaon?

Tags: india, sightseeing

I have recently moved to Gurgaon, and would want to explore some nice sight seeing places around.

I have explored the nice number of malls around. But, I would be more interested in scenic beauty. However, I haven't come across any(atleast around where I stay now, which is Sushant Lok and near my office which is in Cyber City).

So, are there any nice scenic places around which I can explore?

PS:  By scenic places, I mean nature and landscape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gurgaon has a lot to offer to its visitors. You can check out the following places:

**Damdama Lake:**

> Damdamaa reservoir in Sohna, Gurgaon district in the Indian state of
>   Haryana. It is one of the biggest lakes in Haryana and with an area of
>   3,000 acres (12.14 km2). Damdama Lake was formed when a stone and
>   earthen dam constructed by the British was commissioned for rain water
>   harvesting in 1947. [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damdama_Lake)

[image]

**Sultanpur National Park:**

> [Sultanpur National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultanpur_National_Park) (Hindi: सुल्तानपुर राष्ट्रीय वन्यजीव
>   अभयारण्य) (formerly Sultanpur Bird Sanctuary) is located at Sultanpur
>   fifteen kilometres from Gurgaon, Haryana and 50 km from Delhi in
>   India.

[image]

**Sohna:**

> [Sohna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sohna) is a town and a municipal committee in the Gurgaon district
>   of Haryana, India. The City of Sohna is a popular tourist location,
>   especially as a weekend and conference retreat. It is located 24 km
>   from the city on the highway from Gurgaon to Alwar, near a vertical
>   rock. It is famous for its hot springs and ancient Shiva temple.

[image]

**Nuh:**

> The place is the district head quarters of the Mewat district. The
>   place has few historical monuments, like shaking minarets; they are
>   the only vibrating minarets in India. Only due to lack of maintenance
>   it didn't attract many of the tourists. It requires great attention
>   from the government. [(Source)](http://www.mapsofindia.com/gurgaon/places-to-visit.html)

[image]

[And many other places.](http://www.mapsofindia.com/gurgaon/places-to-visit.html)

Answer (score 4):

[Sultanpur National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultanpur_National_Park) is 15km west of Gurgaon and is great for bird watching in the winter because of the large number of migratory birds which come here.

[Asola Bhatti Wild Life Sanctuary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asola_Bhatti_Wildlife_Sanctuary) is 20km east of Gurgaon. It is very large and offers a wide variety of wildlife, captured monkeys from Delhi, nature trails, former mines being reclaimed, and a Conservation Education Centre. ([Directions](http://forest.delhigovt.nic.in/wildlife/asola.html))